# How can I make a React Native alarm clock?

Tags: react-native

I try to make a simple alarm clock. I found this npm package: [React Native Alarm Clock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-alarm-clock)

But when I add everything and start the project, it gives me an error in a command prompt:

> cannot find symbol
> import com.liang.RNAlarmClockPackage;

How do I solve the problem? And is there an alternative to making an alarm clock?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the link you have shared, I found out that there are mistakes in the commands show in given link.

E.g., `react-native link react-native-alarm` in place of `react-native link react-native-alarm-clock`

You can try out below packages

[react-native-calendar-events](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events)

[react-native-alarm-notification](https://github.com/emekalites/react-native-alarm-notification)

Comment: Thx for answering. I tried react-native-alarm but I dont know how to use it. They didnt give an example. Any Idea u have about this ?

Comment: Additionaly, I saw that mistake too but I tried  react-native link react-native-alarm-clock :) but it still gives an error

Comment: i checked the issues related to react-native-alarm in github.It seems it has same issues like react-native-alarm-clock

Comment: you can try react-native-calender-events .

Comment: i am also trying , if it works out then i will share code with you

Comment: try out this  react-native-alarm-notification .Its functionality is explained along with example.